# Как настроить tomcat9 для работы с 2 экземплярами приложений (2 war)

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, tomcat

как можно настроить tomcat 9 для запуска двух war. Разместил оба файла в webapps но при старте tomcat стартует только один сервис, точнее стартуют вроде оба, но доступен по http только одир. Вроде можно через context настроить, пытался прописать в web.xml, но все не удачно.

Comment: Должны оба по дефолта работать. С доступом по адрес-сервера: порт/имя_war_файла

Comment: Доступен только один, на второй 404 валится. Если оставить какой то один из них - любой, то работает(тоесть оба war рабочие)

Comment: Посмотрите на логи. Возможно у вас и там и там БД используется и это вызывает конфликт. Если это так, то попробуйте добавить такое в конфиг: `#fix deploy error
#https://stackoverflow.com/a/37134550/3212712
spring.jmx.default-domain=${my.db.name}
my.db.name=my_db_name`

Comment: @ЮрийСПб Действительно база используется и там и там, точнее это одно приложение, настроенное на разные базы. Но и разные приложения пробовал, тоже не получалось. Но вседа они работали с базами. Спасибо, попробую.

Comment: Главное в предложенном способе - в разных приложениях значения spring.jmx.default-domain должны быть разными

Comment: @ЮрийСПб спаибо, помогло

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Посмотрите на логи. Возможно у вас и там и там БД используется и это вызывает конфликт. Если это так, то попробуйте добавить такое в конфиг:

```
#fix deploy error 
#https://stackoverflow.com/a/37134550/3212712 
spring.jmx.default-domain=${my.db.name} 
my.db.name=my_db_name
```

Тут важно, чтобы значение `spring.jmx.default-domain` было уникальным для каждого `war` файла.